# slideToggle stops functioning after div got updated by Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I experience an issue where .slideToggle() or .slideUp()/.slideDown() stop functioning when the container div data get updated by Ajax. Consider this initial structure:

```
<ul class="main-container">
  <li>
    <div class="data-container"><!--display:none; through CSS-->
      <p>empty</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the slideToggle script:

```
$('.main-container li').click(function(){
    $(this).find('div.data-container').slideToggle();
});
```

Then there is an Ajax update like this:

```
$('.main-container').replaceWith(data)
```

The updated structure becomes:

```
<ul class="main-container">
  <li>
    <div class="data-container"><!--display:none; through CSS-->
      <ol>
        <li>data1</li>
        <li>data2</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then the slideToggle stops functioning until I reload the page. Is there any work around rather than using .slideToggle() or .slideUp()/.slideDown() ?

Comment: Do you replace the main-container ul? through ajax? if it the case then, well like joe said that the event is just getting removed when the you replace it... one way is just to add the event back on straight after the replaceWidth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use:

```
$(document).on('click', '.main-container li', function(){
    $(this).find('div.data-container').slideToggle();
});
```

The issue is that when you replace `.main-container` the original event handler is no longer in effect. To get around this you set the event listener on `document` and ask it to run the function when a `click` event is triggered on an `li` inside the `.main-container` div.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/wXdbL/3/

Comment: @user2395853 - sorry, I forgot that you were replacing the whole div. I've updated it and it should work now.

Comment: This won't work as far as I'm aware as it looks like the maincontainer ul is getting replaced as well, which will remove the event...

Comment: @ryanc1256 - just try the fiddle I provided and click the `Replace` link to replace the entire `main-container` div.

Comment: @Joe yeah... the changes were not there when I was typing and submitted the comment..